# How to return a value from a function based on conditions

Tags: f#

I am not sure why the following function does not compile:

```
let isWithinRange (searchElement:int, recordLength:int) =
    if searchElement = recordLength then true
    elif searchElement > recordLength then false
```

As a result, I have to modify this function just for it to compile:

```
let isWithinRange (searchElement:int, recordLength:int) =
    let mutable withinRange = false
    if searchElement = recordLength then withinRange <- true
    elif searchElement > recordLength then withinRange <- false
    withinRange
```

I don't want to introduce mutability into my code.

Question:

1. Why doesn't my original function compile?
2. What do I need to do to make this function compile without introducing mutability?
3. What's a better way to write this function?

NOTE:

I am new to F#. So please forgive me for this ignorant question.

Comment: Can you update your question with the compile errors you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just missing a final `else (value)`. The structure of your `if` statement is `if...elif`, but you need it to be `if...elif...else`, otherwise there's at least one code path through your function that doesn't return a value. Add `else false` to the end of your original function and your code will compile.

Also, the function name doesn't really make sense. Why are you comparing a search element to a record length? And why is that comparison called `isWithinRange`? As it stands, your function (at least the second version, which compiles) currently follows the following logic:

1. If `searchElement` is equal to `recordLength`, return `true`.
2. In all other cases, return `false`.

That could be written more simply as:

```
let isWithinRange (searchElement:int, recordLength:int) =
    (searchElement = recordLength)
```